# How to run the Linux console tor binary from the Tor browser without launching the Tor browser itself?

Tags: linux

When I tried to run ~/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/tor, it displays the message:
"error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.1.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
The libraries libevent-2.1.so.6, libssl.so.1.1, libcrypto.so.1.1 and libstdc++.so.6 are nearby, but the Tor binary doesn't find them. LD_PRELOAD doesn't help.

The fact is that I already have a system Tor ("systemctl start tor" on port 9050). I need to run another independent copy of the console Tor (on port 9150). They should not interfere with each other. I know that I can launch the Tor browser, but it is very fat. There is another option to run console Tor in Wine, but I would prefer the native way. I use Ubuntu 16.04, Tor Browser 9.0.5.

I spied on the processes while starting the Tor browser. Most likely the command line should be:
~/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/tor --defaults-torrc ~/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc-defaults -f ~/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc --DataDirectory ~/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor --GeoIPFile ~/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/geoip --GeoIPv6File ~/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/geoip6 --SocksPort 127.0.0.1:9150

The site has similar questions. But there advised just to run the tor binary. Apparently, this worked before, but no longer.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to run two separate instances of the tor daemon? One that would work on port 9050 and one that would would on port 9150?

Comment: Yes, two demons at the same time with different settings.

Comment: Can you add what you use for the `LD_PRELOAD`? I don't see why this shouldn't work. And make sure you're running the tor binary while your working directory is `~/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor`, then you shouldn't even need the `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: Running from the working directory didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

It works:

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor ~/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/tor --defaults-torrc ~/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc-defaults -f ~/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc --DataDirectory ~/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor --GeoIPFile ~/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/geoip --GeoIPv6File ~/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/geoip6 --SocksPort 9170

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be possible to do directly with the tor daemon. However, you do have some options.

The easiest option is to simply create a VM that will run the second instance with it's own configuration.

The second option is to run it in in a Docker container. This might be harder to set up if you've never used a container tool before. This will be faster and use less system resources though.

Comment: Unfortunately, Docker is not available for the i686 platform. VM is not the best solution, Wine is better. But, is there really no way to run a portable tor?

Comment: wine is a hack. It's goal is to present a Windows-compatible API to run Windows applications. It has no real security. If you really want to go down that route try Tor Expert Bundle: https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/9.0.5/tor-win32-0.4.2.6.zip. I don't think anyone will try to help running that with Wine though. 

My suggestion: look into using chroot. It's the original Linux container and it will work on 32-bit systems.

Comment: Wine works, but it's a bad solution, of course.